# How to make <input> search filed where it finds the images by html alt attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input search field where i have made it to filter the images by name and display the one that contains the name written  or part of the name. 
But now i want to add the search to be by the attribute `alt` as well . So to display the filtered images by name and tag .

```
  <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Type to search"></input>
  <button onclick="Images()" type="button">SEARCH</button>
  <div class="imgBox"><img id="image_id_009" 
       src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" alt="track"> 
    <p>Title009</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox"><img id="image_id_009" 
       src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" alt="carting"> 
    <p>Title009</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imgBox"><img id="image_id_009" 
       src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" alt="driver"> 
    <p>Title009</p>
  </div>
```

javascript:

```
function Images(){
    let filtering=$("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();
    $(".Box").hide();
    $('.Box').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filtering) !== -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } 
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `|| $("img", this).attr("alt").toLowerCase().indexOf(filtering) !== -1` to your existing `if statement`

```
function Images() {
  let filtering = $("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();
  $(".imgBox").hide();
  $('.imgBox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filtering) !== -1 || $("img", this).attr("alt").toLowerCase().indexOf(filtering) !== -1) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
};
```

*Note* I've changed `$('.Box')` to `$('.imgBox')` to make the example work

**Demo**

```js
function Images() {
  let filtering = $("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();
  $(".imgBox").hide();
  $('.imgBox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(filtering) !== -1 || $("img", this).attr("alt").toLowerCase().indexOf(filtering) !== -1) {
      $(this).show();
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Type to search"></input>
<button onclick="Images()" type="button">SEARCH</button>
<div class="imgBox"><img id="image_id_009" src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" alt="track">
  <p>Title009</p>
</div>
<div class="imgBox"><img id="image_id_009" src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" alt="carting">
  <p>Title009</p>
</div>
<div class="imgBox"><img id="image_id_009" src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" alt="driver">
  <p>Title009</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The alt tag should really be a description of the image for screen readers. If you want to store a category, consider using a data-* attribute.

Maybe use a class on the p + img tags too just to be specific in case anything else gets added in there.

Also there shouldn't really be duplicate id's.

I'd approach it something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Type to search" />
<button onclick="search()" type="button">SEARCH</button>

<div class="imgBox">
    <img class='main-img' src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" data-category="track" alt="Silverstone racetrack finish line"> 
    <p class='title'>Title009</p>
</div>

<div class="imgBox">
    <img class='main-img' src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" data-category="carting" alt="Two carts battling for first place"> 
    <p class='title'>Title009</p>
</div>

<div class="imgBox">
    <img class='main-img' src="Photos/20130610_171751.jpg" data-category="driver" alt="Steve Jones, racing driver, in 1st place on the podium"> 
    <p class='title'>Title009</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function search(){
    let keyword = $("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();
    $(".imgBox").hide();
    $('.imgBox').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).find('.title').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) >= 0 || $(this).find('.main-img').attr('data-category').toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) >= 0) {
            $(this).show();
        } 
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you , this is a good approach as well , i might use it :))

Answer (score 0):

Than you all for  replying . 
Can you tell me , if now i want to filter an array that containes objectcts (JSON file) .
How shall i do it properly?

```
arrayPhotos = [{
    "location": "Photos/_DSC0150.jpg",
    "title": "Title001",
    "id": "image_id_001",
    "tags": [ "building", "city", "hotel"]
  },
  {
    "location": "Photos/_DSC0226.jpg",
    "title": "Title002",
    "id": "image_id_002",
    "tags": [ "fruit", "palm"]
  },
  {
    "location": "Photos/_DSC0442.jpg",
    "title": "Title003",
    "id": "image_id_003",
    "tags": [ "building" , "catedral" , "history"]
  },
]
let inputFilter = $("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();
filteredArrayPhotos = arrayPhotos.filter(function () {

  //Here i need to check if some of the characters in the search field match the
  // ones in `arrayPhotos` .  And if they do , i want those images to added to 
  // `filteredArrayPhotos` 
      })
```

And i have search input field:

```
<input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="Type to search by name"></input>
    <button onclick="filterImagesByName()" type="button">Search</button>
```